# Exporting MySQL data to xml using PHP - HTML encoding and general error BRAIN MELT

Tags: php, html, xml, encoding, cdata

Anyone who can answer my question deserves a BIG FAT GOLD MEDAL OF AWESOMENESS!

I'm trying to get  the contents of a MySQL table into a nice, easy XML format. I'm running a bit of PHP which works great and I can see XML (Good times). However, in the MySQL table there are a couple of fields which are populated with non-encoded HTML table code. I'm wrapping each field value that I get inside CDATA tags, I've made sure that the xml tags are being closed, but I'm wondering if I'm missing something because it's erroring and I can't see why (Bad times). It looked fine to me, so I tried to open this in Excel (as that's how the client will see it) it claimed that the start tag of "package" was matched with an end tag of "long_description".

http://www.shavesgreensafaris.com/display.php is the page that I'm working on so you can see the data there.

This is the code I'm using...

```
        $xml          = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
        $root_element = "packages";
        $xml         .= "<$root_element>";


        if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
        {
           while($result_array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
           {
              $xml .= "<package>";

              //loop through each key,value pair in row
              foreach($result_array as $key => $value)
              {
                 //$key holds the table column name
                 $xml .= "<$key>";

                 //embed the SQL data in a CDATA element to avoid XML entity issues
                 $xml .= "<![CDATA[$value]]>"; 

                 //and close the element
                 $xml .= "</$key>";
              }

              $xml.="</package>";
           }
        }

//close the root element
$xml .= "</$root_element>";

//send the xml header to the browser
header ("Content-Type:text/xml"); 

//output the XML data
echo $xml;
```

What ON EARTH am I doing wrong?!

---

### EDIT

OK, so there appears to be something that removes one "<" from a long_description tag around line 310 - you can search in the view source if you want to see it as ">long_description>" - something really weird has happened and the tag isn't properly formed. I wasn't entirely sure HOW this could happen as the code I'm using definitely puts opening and closing angle brackets on all $keys. It only happens once, but it seems to stuff everything else up.

Anyone know why this might be occurring?

Any help HUGELY appreciated, and thanks in advance!

Gem

Comment: Are you sure, the xml is working? it returns `XML Parsing Error: not well-formed` near `3 X day Stag hunt`.

Comment: yes, there is a problem on the last but one package (Red stag package) - the <cost> and <fees> elements are not well-formed

Comment: Ah yes - something is eating one of the opening tags on

Comment: (sorry, mashed the keyboard...) the long_description around this line: ...daily rate.</p>]]></long_description><short_description><![CDATA[<p>This 10...

Weird...

Comment: As well as that problem you guys mentioned...!

Comment: "because it's erroring and I can't see why" unless you tell us how it's erroring and with what message we cannot see why either.

Comment: @Gordon 

This page contains the following errors:

error on line 3583 at column 1228: Encoding error
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Comment: Did you tried by escaping your data ? `$value`

Comment: Thanks @Sanjay but how do you mean? I'm using cdata around each value which I thought would pretty much cover any issue with encoding. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Try by making a small change, `"<![CDATA[" . htmlspecialchars($value) . "]]>"` And sorry i meant convert to entities instead escaping :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel that [DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) would be the way to approach this. The code may look somewhat more cumbersome at first glance, but it will take care of all the output formatting for you:

```
<?php

  // The names of the root node and the node that will contain a row
  $root_element = "packages";
  $row_element = "package";

  // Create the DOMDocument and the root node
  $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
  $rootNode = $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement($root_element));

  // Loop the DB results
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    // Create a row node
    $rowNode = $rootNode->appendChild($dom->createElement($row_element));

    // Loop the columns
    foreach ($row as $col => $val) {

      // Create the column node and add the value in a CDATA section
      $rowNode->appendChild($dom->createElement($col))
              ->appendChild($dom->createCDATASection($val));

    }

  }

  // Output as string
  echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Comment: If I could demonstrate all the ways I love you right about now, I ruddy would. Thanks, this has made light of what was fast becoming a world of pain. ALL HAIL DAVERANDOM etc.